# The trial period system along with subscription - PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I built a trial period system using PHP and Mysql and it is working completely fine. But what I'm trying to achieve is that it should automatically update the time period, once the user buys the subscription. For example, if a user signs up for 30 days subscription, then it should increase by 30 days.

I'm not expecting someone to write the code for me. Just want to know how it could be done. Because this is the first time I'm building such a thing. Need your guidance on it!

and I know code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. You can ignore it because this is just for testing purpose

```
<?php 

session_start();

include 'db-connection.php';

   $user_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['user_email']);
   $user_pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['user_pass']);
   
   $select_user = "select * from users where user_email='$user_email'";
   $select_user_query = mysqli_query($connection, $select_user);
   $user_email_count = mysqli_num_rows($select_user_query);

   if($user_email_count) {
       $user_result_array = mysqli_fetch_array($select_user_query);
       $user_db_pass = $user_result_array['user_pass'];
       $user_id = $user_result_array['user_id'];
       $user_name = $user_result_array['user_name'];
       
     
       
       if($user_pass === $user_db_pass ) {
           $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
           $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name;
           
       $user_registration_date = new DateTime($user_result_array['user_registration']); // This fetch the user registration date from database
       $today_date = new DateTime();
       $trial_period = 7;
       $date_diff = date_diff($user_registration_date,$today_date);
       $date_difference = $date_diff->format('%d days');
           
           if($date_difference >= $trial_period){
             echo "Trial period is over";
           } else {
             echo "<span class='alert alert-success'>Login Successful</span>";
           }
       
       } else {
           echo "<span class='alert alert-danger'>You have entered wrong password</span>";
       }
       
   } else {
       echo "<span class='alert alert-danger'>No Record Found</span>";
   }

?>
```

Once the trial period is over, it would redirect the user to the trial.php page where the user would be asked to do the payment.

Once the payment is made, it should increase the time period (this is the step which I don't know how to achieve)

User Table

```
User_id | user_registration | user_name | user_email | user_pass | user_phone
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add **`expiry_date`** column in user table (which will be added auto after registration.. like **`current_date + 30 days`**. Plus add one more column **`fees_paid=0`**.
2. If you are using payment gateway for payment, then **send auto email with payment link to user before trial period expires**. If user make payment, update database **`expiry_date`** with **`registartion_date + 60 days`** (or XX Days, you want to add) and **`fees_paid=1`** alogn with other payment details like payment date, payment_id etc... via webhook response along with payment details.
3. If you are not using payment gateway and collecting payment via neft / cash etc., then via your admin panel, activate user's account by **`adding desired days in registration_date`** of user.

In database, you can add some columns like **`fees_paid = 0`** / **`fees_paid = 1`** (0 for not paid and 1 for paid), **`order_number= random_generated_unique_string`**,  **`payment_date`**, **`payment_id`** etc for saving payment details.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much

Comment: But I'm having doubt about this (registartion_date + 60 days). Because let's assume If the user registered on 1st January and decided to subscribe to the plan on 5th January, then it should + the days from 5th January (the day payment is made) instead of from registration date (1st January)

Comment: then add xx days in payment date